# Reload certain div after certain amount of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently testing a twitter wall for a client and I am loading the wall when the page starts with javascript. Is there a possibility to reload the div or javascript without having to reload the browser?

This is my div

```
<div id="social-stream"></div>
```

Loading it with js

```
$(document).ready(function($){
$('#social-stream').dcSocialStream({
    feeds: {
        twitter: {
            id: '#%23hashtag',
            thumb: true,
            images:'medium',
        },

    },
    rotate: {
        delay: 0
    },
    twitterId: 'something',
    control: false,
    filter: false,
    wall: true,
    cache: false,
    max: 'limit',
    limit: 16,
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can, by using [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval) like,

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    function socialStream() {
        $('#social-stream').html('').dcSocialStream({
            feeds: {
                twitter: {
                    id: '#%23swiss',
                    thumb: true,
                    images: 'medium',
                },

            },
            rotate: {
                delay: 0
            },
            twitterId: 'swiss',
            control: false,
            filter: false,
            wall: true,
            cache: false,
            max: 'limit',
            limit: 16,
        });

    }
    socialStream();// first time load
    setInterval(function () {
        socialStream(); // reload div after every 5 seconds
    }, 5000); // 5 seconds interval
});
```

And also you can use [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.clearInterval) to stop the reloading/refreshing your twitter data

Comment: Thanks Rohan, it doesn't reload anything though, if you want, you can check the test-site here: http://goo.gl/NjT1BK (its still very early stage :P)

Comment: @Paranoia you can make a html page and call it by ajax with `cache:false` along with setInterval. See [Comments on dcSocialStreamPlugin](http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-social-stream/2103997/comments?page=39)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I put the <div class="social-stream"></div> in a separate html file (stream.html) and load it every 20 seconds with ajax. The plugin itself does not load anymore, I think I maybe forgot something (the code is live on the test-site)

Comment: Remove the `refresh id ` from body tag and make a div in body and apply that id to the div, currently, it would replace the stream code in body and your script and other elements would vanish.

Comment: Thanks Rohan! It works now (I also forgot to add the js to the loaded html, tzzz). It would be amazing if I could let the content fade-out when it is reloaded, but i dont have any idea how i could do that.

Comment: Yes, I think you don't need to load the js again and again, just load at first time in your master page and load the content from twitter in interval.
Also if you want to use fadeOut then you must have to use fadeIn to show your twitter feeds somthing like, `$("#refresh").fadeOut('fast').load('stream.html?' + 1*new Date()).fadeIn(500);`

Answer (score 0):

```
var container = $('#social-stream');
$(document).ready(function($){
    loadTweets();
    setInterval(loadTweets,200);
});

function loadTweets(){
container.empty();
container.dcSocialStream({
    feeds: {
        twitter: {
            id: '#%23swiss',
            thumb: true,
            images:'medium',
        },

    },
    rotate: {
        delay: 0
    },
    twitterId: 'swiss',
    control: false,
    filter: false,
    wall: true,
    cache: false,
    max: 'limit',
    limit: 16,
    });
}
```